# Excluding certain Contexts while Matching or Replacing

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

**I am using angular 4 with typescript.**

```
let string1 = "I love chicken so much. but I don't like chickensoup. Do you love itemchicken";

let blockWord = "chick";

let safeWord = "chicken"
```

I am here finding the blokword "chick" and replacing it with the span tag with highlight class to highlight the blockWords in the string1.

```
   let regex_escaped_block_word = blockWord.replace(/[\*?{}().+]/gi, '\\$&');
   string1= string1.replace(new RegExp(regex_escaped_block_word, 'gi'), "<span class='highlight'>" + blockWord + '</span>');
```

Result:

> I love **chick**en so much. but I don't like **chick**ensoup. Do you love item**chick**en

Want to achieve:

> I want to exclude the exact safeWord "chicken" from regex scanning so that it won't get highlighted and result will look like

Expected result:

> I love chicken so much. but I don't like **chick**ensoup. Do you love item**chick**en

Comment: sorry for that now i have corrected it

Comment: You should capture safe word first then look for block word: `\b(chicken)\b|chick` or use a negative lookahead: `\b(?!chicken\b)(\w*)(chick)`

Comment: @revo i followed your solution -
let newregex = new RegExp('\\b(?!chicken\\b)(\\w*)('+regex_escaped_stop_words+')', 'gi');
it didnt highlight the chicken but it replaced itemchicken with chicken

Comment: result now-  I love chicken so much. but I don't like chickensoup. Do you love chicken.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/dpnf5tb4/

Comment: thank you I figured it out my own. and it looks like - 
let newregex = new RegExp('\\b(?!chicken\\b)(\\w*)('+regex_escaped_stop_words+')(\\w*)', 'gi');
str1 = str1.replace(newregex, '$1'+"<span class='marked'>" + '$2' + '</span>'+'$3');

Comment: @rev thanks for your help though